# Accidently renamed the ld-linux-aarch64.so.1

Tags: command-line, bash, unity-dash

On my Ubuntu command line system, I accidentally renamed the `/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1` file.
This led to behavior that I cannot use any bash/dash/sh commands and cannot use `mv` any more to revert the file name. There are not many commands that I can execute and passing `/bin/bash` or `/bin/dash` as command is also not working and keeps saying: `-bash: /bin/dash: No such file or directory`, `-bash: /bin/ls: No such file or directory`.

Is there any way to get out of this state and recover?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127578/discussion-on-question-by-ubuntuissues-accidently-renamed-the-ld-linux-aarch64-s).

Answer (score 2):

This is done on 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa). On the grub menu, you press 'c' to bring up a `grub>` prompt.

```
grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz
grub> initrd /boot/initrd.img
grub> boot
```

This will boot into an initramfs (busybox) shell:

```
(initramfs) mkdir /mnt
(initramfs) mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
(initramfs) cd /mnt/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
(initramfs) ls ld-*
ld-renamed.so*
(initramfs) # Your ld.so version may differ
(initramfs) # (bionic 18.04 is ld-2.27.so)
(initramfs) cp -i -a ld-renamed.so ld-2.31.so
(initramfs) ln -s ld-2.31.so ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(initramfs) ls -F ld-*
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2@  ld-2.31.so*
```